# Combining 2 columns into one using INDIRECT in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a Spreadsheet with multiple sheets. 
In one of them I'm trying to populate a column combining the value of two columns from another sheet.

Something like: **Col1**: City, **Col2**: Country **->** In new Sheet, **Location** = (Col2),  (Col1).

I've tried this but so far no luck:

```
=INDIRECT("FormaData!P2:P"&"FormData!O2:O")
```

FormData is the name of the external sheet, and the columns that I'm trying to automatically populate from are:

P2 to end of P (city) and O2 to end of O (country).

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Why not in your first cell `=FormaData!P2 & ", " & FormaData!O2` and copy down?

Comment: I did this `=INDIRECT(FormData!P2&", "&FormData!O2)`, and it gives me error: `Function INDIRECT parameter 1 value is 'Barcelona, España'. It is not a valid cell/range reference.`

Comment: Don't use the indirect. Just the formula straight

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work all the way down

```
=arrayformula('FormaData'!P2:P&", "&'FormaData'!O2:O)
```

Are you using a different spreadsheet altogether? If so you need to modify it to use import range:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IMPORTRANGE("spreadsheet url","'FormaData'!P2:P")&","&(IMPORTRANGE("spreadsheet url","'FormaData'!O2:O")))
```